# Django session sharing between projects

Tags: python, django, session, cookies, session-cookies

I have two projects which must share session between them. One project is in `domain.com`, second - `domain.com/app`. I setup `SESSION_COOKIE_NAME = 'pr1'` and `SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN = 'domain.com'` on each project. But my users must login twice.

What I'm doing wrong?

UPD. Projects are on same database.

Comment: Do the projects share the database? Sessions are stored there by default.

Comment: You should make sure both of the projects fetch from same data source for sessions, such as single DB table or cache instance.

Comment: Also, IIRC, on legacy Django versions, the secret key counts and should be same, or else you need to customize the backend.

Comment: Yes, they are in same database